# How can I allow access to REST by IP basis?

Tags: api, google-kubernetes-engine, firewall

I would like to block access to a rest API, so that the world can't access it and only predefined IPs could. My back-end is a Java service but I would like to separate this layer of security from the code, and apply it as an external tool. some kind of Firewall for endpoints. For an example:

[image]

I'm working with GKE.

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-concepts) to allow access to your app only to specific IP addresses or CIDR ranges. It [integrates with GKE](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#configuring_for) and fits exactly the use case you described. Just note that it's currently in beta and may not be suitable for production depending on your requirements.

Comment: Hi, appreciate the response! my need is for specific path on servers, like https://192.0.0.1/v2/test, because I would like everyone could reach the webserver but not to the /test API. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Then perhaps Load balancing with UTL-Maps is the solution for you, you can discriminate based on requests (which IPs go to which path, in your case /rest path or default webserver).  You can check on with detail in [https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts] and I think that will be the best way (and less painful) to achieve what you require.

Answer (score 0):

As GKE are, in the end, a bunch of VMs, you can use firewall rules to block IPs (or allow IPs) to access your end points; remember the flow of the data

```
 Internet -> Google Cloud (firewall) -> Validation -> Services (VMs, GKE, AppEngine, etc.)
```

There is this document: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/prep-kubernetes-engine-for-prod that may come in handy, specially the part where it says: Firewalling, you can use this as a guide to create the firewall rules you require to cover your needs and perhaps, even extend it for better security.

Just remember, create your rules with the access required and no more (if you are using just one port, give access to that one port only not to a bunch) and avoid the 0.0.0.0/0 rule is better to create pinholes than an open door.

Update: 
As the requester explained better, I think the best shot to achieve faster (and better) results will be using a Load balancing with URL Maps, that way the backend services will be untouched and the IP path discrimination will be at the upper level. The information can be found in [https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts]

If you require more help, just let me know ;)

-JP

Comment: Actually Firewall Rules apply to your project's network, and the Load Balancer sits outside of this network. You need to create a FW rule to allow traffic from the LB to your instances, as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#firewall_rules). Anyone who can access the LB's public IP can then access your instances. You need to filter access to the LB upstream. GCP offers Cloud Armor to do so.